# Why doesn’t the test function in Alexa developer console work on iPad Pro

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I get the proper JSON response but I don’t hear any audio or see any text of the response. It all works fine on any windows pc when I go through the exact same process. I know it’s not a problem with my skill Or the browser. I only experience this on my 3rd generation iPad Pro (Regardless of any browser, incognito or private settings that I change).

Comment: Hi Corbett, welcome to SO, we need some more details and [mcve](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: I didn't think that any code was necessary since it's not really a question of coding.  Anyone can simply try the test tab on the amazon developer console (on an ipad pro) using any skill they choose.  I'm new to SO and this is my first question on this site.  I have an open ticket with amazon regarding this issue but I haven't heard back from them in weeks.  If you don't have access to an ipad pro, I do not think you would ever encounter this problem.